# Dataframes from dictionnaries in nested lists - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have for example a nested list of 2 lists containing dictionaries like this : [[{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{},{}]]

```
[[{'Date': 'Dec 16 2020', 'Open': '37.00', 'High': '37.71', 'Low': '36.65', 'Close': '36.67', 'Adj Close': '36.67', 'Volume': '1840194'}, {'Date': 'Dec 15 2020', 'Open': '35.80', 'High': '36.88', 'Low': '35.63', 'Close': '36.79', 'Adj Close': '36.79', 'Volume': '1683816'}, {'Date': 'Dec 14 2020', 'Open': '35.48', 'High': '36.63', 'Low': '35.48', 'Close': '35.74', 'Adj Close': '35.74', 'Volume': '1808091'}, {'Date': 'Dec 11 2020', 'Open': '36.29', 'High': '36.63', 'Low': '34.96', 'Close': '35.08', 'Adj Close': '35.08', 'Volume': '1947461'}, {'Date': 'Dec 10 2020', 'Open': '36.51', 'High': '36.88', 'Low': '35.47', 'Close': '36.35', 'Adj Close': '36.35', 'Volume': '2207529'}],[{'Date': 'Sep 22 2020', : lose': '22.17', 'VolOpen': '22.00', 'High': '22.87', 'Low': '21.89', 'Close': '22.87', 'Adj Close': '22.87', 'Volume': '1997258'}, {'Date': 'Oct 05 2020', 'Open': '21.60', 'High': '
'Open': '21.01', 'High': '21.85', 'Low': '20.74', 'Close': '21.43', 'Adj Close': '21.43', 'Volume': '2064940'}, {'Date': 'Sep 21'O, 'Volume': '2064940 '20.72', 'Close': '21.19', 'Adj Close': '21.19', 'Volume': '2007302'}, {'Date': 'Oct 01 2020', 'Open': '22.35', 'High': '22.XMRClose': '20.88', 'Adj Close': '20.88', 'Volume': '3544256'}]]
```

I would like 2 dataframes something like :

```
          Date  Open  High  Low  Close Adj Close Volume 
   Dec 16 2020    37    37   36         36      1840194 
   Dec 15 2020     '     '    '          '            '
   Dec 14 2020     '     '    '          '            '
   Dec 13 2020     '     '    '          '            '
```

And I obviously can't use that :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

with data as a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Please format your input data as a valid Python object.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: If I try to copy-paste your example data into Python, I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Please fix the syntax errors (e.g. closing strings with quotes, use columns between keys and values in the dictionary, separate key-value pairs with commas) so that we can test your code using the provided data.

Comment: it's values that I get after crawling a website. That's also half of the question i'm asking.

Comment: In fact, I know how to create a datafram with : [{],{],{],{}] and with data like the sample I gave you but not like I asked.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the correct result into your question? For example, in one of the lists you have a dictionary which reads `{'Date': 'Sep 22 2020', : lose': '22.17' ...`. That's not valid Python - the second element is not a key-value pair, and the string is broken. it looks like there's a piece of the dictionary missing in there. If this is in fact your actual result after webscraping, then you need to sanitize it prior to parsing it into a dafaframe.

Comment: Doesn't matter how the value are, if I keep only one list and I create a dataframe, it's working like charm. but how to create different dataframe in a loop for every list inside the main list.

Comment: it does matter because we're trying to help you. And it's much harder to do that if you can't provide valid input data for your problem.

Comment: I understand, and I thank you for that, but i'm not asking about the values inside, I'm asking about creating different dataframe through the different lists

Comment: I know how to create a dataframe for dictionnaries in one list then how to do it for many list in one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simply to flatten your list of lists, then you can pass it to pandas normally

```
l = [
  [{'date':1, 'value':'1'}, {'date':2, 'value':'2'}],
  [{'date':3, 'value':'3'}, {'date':4, 'value':'4'}]
]
df = pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in l for item in sublist])
```

Will get you

```
   date   value
0     1     '1'
1     2     '2'
2     3     '3'
3     4     '4'
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

While if you need a list of pandas DataFrames you can simply iterate your main list like so:

```
df_list = []
for x in l:
     df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(x))
```

Or simply

```
df_list = [pd.DataFrame(x) for x in l]
```

Comment: Hello Nicolo thank you for your answer, i would like it to be 2 dataframes separated could you edit your answer please ? The first list as one and the second list as another one.

Comment: Using a loop and not declaring another df

Comment: Just what I needed thank you for your patience and sorry if I was not clear at the beginning.